# Multiple preview image and delete

Tags: jquery

### HTML

I have the following HTML code for the preview results

```
 <div class="gallery"></div>
```

## JS

This javascript code function is to make multiple image previews.

But I don't know how to make a code to delete every photo preview

```
 $(function() {

  var imagesPreview = function(input, placeToInsertImagePreview) {

      if (input.files) {
        var filesAmount = input.files.length;

        for (i = 0; i < filesAmount; i++) {
            var reader = new FileReader();

            reader.onload = function(event) {
              $($.parseHTML('<img>')).attr('src', event.target.result).attr('class','prevImage').appendTo(placeToInsertImagePreview);   
            }

            reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[i]);
        }
      }

  };

  $('#gallery-photo-add').on('change', function() {
    imagesPreview(this, 'div.gallery');
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/2e6br85s/

Things what I have did:
1) Added a div wrapper for a preview image.
2) Then after added a "Remove" anchor tag inside that wrapper. Created a function for removing the complete wrapper div whenever user clicks on the "Remove" anchor tag.

JS Code:

```
$(function() {
  var imagesPreview = function(input, placeToInsertImagePreview) {
      if (input.files) {
        var filesAmount = input.files.length;

        for (i = 0; i < filesAmount; i++) {
            var reader = new FileReader();

            reader.onload = function(event) {
              var imgElement = $($.parseHTML('<img>')).attr('src', event.target.result).attr('class','prevImage').appendTo(placeToInsertImagePreview);
              imgElement.wrap('<div class="img-preview col-md-4"></div>');
              imgElement.parent().append('<p><a class="remove-image-preview" href="javascript:void(0);">Remove</a></p>');
            }

            reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[i]);
        }
      }
  };

  $('#gallery-photo-add').on('change', function() {
    imagesPreview(this, 'div.gallery');
  });

  $(document).on('click', 'a.remove-image-preview', function(){
    $(this).closest('.img-preview').remove();
  });
});
```

Comment: Correct, because as per your question you just need to have image preview removed. And that's the only thing suggested in an answer. You can make use of an AJAX based image upload. And when final form gets submitted along with data, that time you can pass only it's related image paths during final form submission. For AJAX based image upload have a look at the url: https://makitweb.com/how-to-upload-image-file-using-ajax-and-jquery/